# What are the benefits of purple drywall?

Tags: drywall, basement, mold

I am about to drywall a basement.  Go purple?  Can purple be used around showers?  Are there any additional costs or install problems with the purple drywall?  Does it require any extra steps?  Why would I install it?

And this is the [Purple](http://www.nationalgypsum.com/products/Product.aspx?ProductID=2413) stuff I am talking about.

Also I like to consider myself a progressive person.  If the purple drywall is the same cost why wouldn't it be installed by default?

Comment: Check out [Why PURPLE®](http://askforpurple.com/why-purple/). If I remember correctly, code doesn't allow drywall in wet areas (tub/shower surround).

Comment: If you like purple walls, you don't need to paint it? :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure. I thought it'd be an easy answer but googling seems to return two different types:

- High Density (stronger) wall board
- and an updated version of green board (mildew resistant)

It may be that the color is being used by different manufacturers for different reasons.

In either case, for a basement, I'd suggest using something else. I'd go with the paper-less sheetrock options such as [DensArmor](http://www.buildgp.com/densarmorplus-high-performance-gypsum-panels)

The 'pro' is that there is no paper, so no place for mold/mildew to grow. Instead it uses a fiberglass mesh. The 'con' is that it's fiberglass. So itchy. Be sure to wear long sleeve shirt and gloves while hanging it.

Comment: Fiberglass faced board also has a slight texture that some people object to and sometimes a skim coat is put on top if you want a very smooth surface.

Comment: @bib yes. Excellent point! The first time I used it I mudded all the seams and didn't skim coat. Wasn't noticeable in the basement unless you got your eyes right up to the board and then in the right light, you could see the mud vs. non mudded areas (mudded being smoother).

Comment: It costs more... So I was thinking about drywalling horizontally and using this for the bottoms everywhere in the basement if that makes sense.  I didn't know it had a texture so not sure how it will match with the top.  Anything else - like thickness variations compared to regular drywall?  They don't carry this at the big boxes near me so I have to order it in.

Comment: @DMoore I think I got the Densarmor from Menards or Home Depot. It should be standard thicknesses to match any sheetrock.

Comment: We just got our first Menards - I have yet to check it out.  What is the price of the densarmour for an 8 foot sheet at 1/2 inch?

Comment: I don't recall the price. I don't think it was a lot more than the standard stuff.